# Do i need to call BasicPublish and BasicAck in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I am working on a simple Request / Response Client for `RabbitMQ`. The sender part of this system is handled elsewhere. My service is only in charge of receicing messages, processing them and replying with `Acks` or `Nacks`, respectively.

A very simple question has come up, but i cannot figure it out. Do i need to call `BasicPublish` before calling `BasicAck` or is `BasicAck` (or `BasicNack`) enough?

As i understand from the docs, `BasicPublish` will send the message to the queue. However, i call `BasicAck` too. So shouldn't it be enough to call `BasicAck` alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your queue is configured to require [consumer acknowledgements](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html), then you only have to call `BasicAck`. I am assuming that you are consuming messages using the `basic.consume` or `basic.get` AMQP methods.

`BasicPublish` publishes messages, as you have noted.